# Sacar diferencia de tiempo en minutos tablas diferentes SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo que restar dos columnas de tablas diferentes una de tipo Time y otra de tipo decimal(que tengo que pasar a tipo time para poder obtener la diferencia de tiempo), en la de tipo decimal tengo 44.25 que en horas son 44:15  y en el campo de tipo time tengo 00:29:29.0000000.
Entonces lo que tengo que quiero es la diferencia entre esos dos campos, tengo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
T1.Nombre,CONVERT(time, DATEADD(MS, SUM(DATEDIFF(MS,'00:00:00.000', 
T1.TiempoPiso)),'00:00:00.000')) AS Sum_TiempoPiso,
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(T2.TimeWeek) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + 
CAST(FLOOR((((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 3600) / 60)) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 60) AS VARCHAR), 2) as 
TotalHoras
FROM
Registros T1, staff T2
where T1.Nombre='nombre' and T2.nombre = 'nombre'
GROUP BY
T1.Nombre,T2.TimeWeek
```

todo esto me da lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo sacarla diferencia?

Comment: As probado de realizar una resta entre las 2 columnas, cuando ya tienes las columnas en los mismos tipos de datos haces `select a.columnaA - a.columnaB as ColumnaC from ( select xxxx ) a` ?

Comment: si ya, pero como el campo tipo decimal lo casteo me tira el error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator.

Comment: leyendo un poco en internet se puede hacer con Datediff pero necesita 3 argumentos(datepart,startime,endtime), entonces tengo que pasar esto RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR(T2.TimeWeek) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + 
CAST(FLOOR((((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 3600) / 60)) AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST (FLOOR((T2.TimeWeek * 3600) % 60) AS VARCHAR), 2) a time ya que asi como esta solo tiene en formato time pero no es time en si, como paso todo esto a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor creo yo es llevar todo a una misma unidad de medida, en este caso yo elegí llevar todo a minutos y restar de esa forma. Por ejemplo:

29:29 (mm:ss) --> 29.4833333333333 en minutos

44:15 (hh:mm) --> 2655 en minutos

el resultado sera de: 2626.48333333333 minutos --> 43:46 horas

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE ([Time] time, [TotalHoras] decimal(4,2))

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('00:29:29.0000000','44.15')

SELECT 
     DATEPART(minute,[Time]) + (DATEPART(second,[Time]) / CONVERT(float,60)) AS [Total Minutes 1]
    ,(CAST([TotalHoras] AS int) * 60) + 15 AS [Total Minutes 2]
    ,((CAST([TotalHoras] AS int) * 60) + 15) - DATEPART(minute,[Time]) + (DATEPART(second,[Time]) / CONVERT(float,60)) AS [Diff]
FROM @TABLE


DECLARE @A int = 2626.48333333333 --> result of diff
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), @A/ 60  + (@A% 60) / 100.0)
```

Claramente, el código se puede pulir aún más.
Espero te sirva.

Comment: tiene sentido tu respuesta, pero como le paso en una variable el valor a @A? ya que ese valor es el calculado dentro del Select?

Comment: La estructura es solo un ejemplo, lo interesante para ti es dejar el resultado de la columna [Diff] en una variable del tipo que más te convenga. `SET @A = ((CAST([TotalHoras] AS int) * 60) + 15) - DATEPART(minute,[Time]) + (DATEPART(second,[Time]) / CONVERT(float,60))` por ejemplo

Comment: me sirvio para darme mas idea de como configurar el query y ya obtengo lo que buscaba, saludos.